# Measure nonzero implies dense on a rectangle

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, self-learning

This would be a very handy lemma for me but I have been unable to prove it thus far.

> If $S \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and is not of measure zero, then there exists a rectangle $R$ such that $S$ is dense in $R$.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to prove it? Can someone provide a counterexample?

Thank you!
Brian

Edit: I should have clarified what I meant (moreover this may not be (or even worse, it could be completely different from) the standard definition of dense): $S$ is dense on $R$ if for every $x \in R$, if $\epsilon > 0$ then there exists $y \in S$: $|x-y| < \epsilon$.

Again thank you for the wealth of responses.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by $S$ dense in $R$, to avoid confusion? That every point of $R$ belongs to $\overline{S}$ the closure of $S$? Or that $\overline{S}=R$? In any case, the result is false. But it is harder in the former case.

Comment: In case you mean the former, it is trivially true if you allow your rectangle to be a singleton. But nontrivially false if the rectangles are assumed to be nonempty. This amounts to showing that $S$ can have empty interior, even though it has positive measure. The usual example is a fat Cantor set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}$, as mentioned by Ittay Weiss. Then $C^n$ is your counterample in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: julien, I meant the former.

Answer (score 3):

Any fat Cantor set in $\mathbb R$ has positive measure yet is not dense in any segment. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = B(0,1)$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then no such $R$ exist (draw the picture in the $n = 2$ case).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't make sense, since you can just pick $R$ inside of the ball.  However, I don't think your lemma is right.  Here's an exercise: construct a Cantor set of positive measure  (i.e. a totally disconnected, compact subset of $[0,1]$).

Comment: It depends on what the user means. I was thinking we need $\bar{S} = R$, which cannot happen if $R$ is a proper subset of $S$.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems obviously wrong.  A circle x^2 + y^2 <= 1 is obviously not dense in any rectangle.

Comment: the circle also doesn't have positive measure in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: In view of the <= in the answer, Keshav presumably meant "disk" rather than "circle"; but then it *is* dense in any rectangle that lies inside the disk.

Comment: Yes, I did mean disk.  But I thought A being dense in B means that A is a subset of B whose closure is B.